# Different :deploy_to per role

Tags: php, ruby, deployment, capistrano

i use capistrano for PHP app deployment and i ran into this issue, i have s one app that i need to deploy onto 3 different servers. Now capistrano has roles for setting up multiple servers per environment. And role takes options, from what i have found out here it should be able to take :deploy_to as deployment path for each server. Unfortunatelly it does not work.

I am doing it like this:

```
role :app, "s1", {:user => "u1", :deploy_to => "/home/u1/releases/app" }
role :app, "s2", {:user => "u2", :deploy_to => "/home/u2/releases/app" }
role :app, "s3", {:user => "u3", :deploy_to => "/home/u3/releases/app" }
```

:user is correctly set how ever, :deploy_to is not being used by tasks. Does anyone has anyidea how to fix this?

Thank you